# Specific website wont let me get the links from their Page

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi there is seems to work on most webpages but I don't understand why it wont bring back the links for this website. Do anyone know why? Looking at the source there is stuff like: 
"a href="https://thebillingtongroup.com/food-group/billington-foodservice/" which it should bring back.

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://thebillingtongroup.com/')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use request headers:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://thebillingtongroup.com/', headers=headers)
...
```

Some websites require a valid `User-Agent` to process the request.

Comment: Thank you that worked I cant give you tick yet because you answered too quickly. Ill add it later